Defining fixtures with variable import paths
I am testing functions from different modules that use an imported helper function from helpers.py.  I am monkeypatching this helper function in each module function's test (please see below).  I would like to put setup_do_thing() and mock_do_thing() in a conftest.py file to cut down on repetition and remove general_mocks.py, but am unable to do this due to the different import paths supplied to monkeypatch.setattr() in test_module_1.py and test_module_2.py.
Is there a way to put the fixture in a single file and supply to multiple test modules?
app/helper.py:
def do_thing():
    #do_thing

app/module1.py:
from helper import do_thing

def use_do_thing_for_x():
    ...
    do_thing()
    ...

app/module2.py:
from helper import do_thing

def use_do_thing_for_y():
    ...
    do_thing
    ...

tests/general_mocks.py:
def mock_do_thing():
    #do_other_thing

tests/test_module_1.py:
from general_mocks import mock_do_thing

@pytest.fixture
def setup_do_thing(monkeypatch):
    monkey_patch.setattr('app.module1.do_thing', 
                         mock_do_thing)
    
def test_use_do_thing_for_x(setup_do_thing):
    ...

tests/test_module_2.py:
from general_mocks import mock_do_thing

@pytest.fixture
def setup_do_thing(monkeypatch):
    monkey_patch.setattr('app.module2.do_thing', 
                         mock_do_thing)
    
def test_use_do_thing_for_y(setup_do_thing):
    ...


If you want to do this, you have to parametrize your fixture in some way, as it cannot guess the correct module. First comes to mind indirect parametrization, e.g. something like:
conftest.py
@pytest.fixture
def setup_do_thing(monkeypatch, request):
    # error handling omitted
    monkeypatch.setattr(f"app.{request.param}.do_thing",
                        mock_do_thing)

test_module1.py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("setup_do_thing", ["module1"], indirect=True)
def test_use_do_thing_for_x(setup_do_thing):
    use_do_thing_for_x()

If you don't like because it somewhat misuses parametrization, you can for example define your own marker instead:
conftest.py
def pytest_configure(config):
    # register your marker
    config.addinivalue_line(
        "markers", "do_thing_module: module where 'do_thing' resides"
    )

@pytest.fixture
def setup_do_thing(monkeypatch, request):
    mark = request.node.get_closest_marker("do_thing_module")
    if mark:
        # use the first marker argument as module name
        # error handling omitted
        monkeypatch.setattr(f"app.{mark.args[0]}.do_thing",
                            mock_do_thing)

test_module1.py
@pytest.mark.do_thing_module("module1")
def test_use_do_thing_for_x(setup_do_thing):
    use_do_thing_for_x()

There are probably more possibilities to do this, but these came to mind first.
